# How to read multiple requests via MySqlReader C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, reader

I have problem , read only first record and must be 5 record from db. Help me to solve this proble . I have 3 request in 1 command , i think that it work not normal for me .

**Screenshot of records in DB**

[image: Screenshot of records]

**Result**

[image: Records]

```
    var model = new List<WorkPeriod1>();
        MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT target_date FROM work_period w, aspnetusers u WHERE u.Id=w.id_manager AND u.UserType=0 AND u.Id_num<>0 AND u.IsActive = TRUE AND w.target_date >= DATE_SUB('2018-04-21',INTERVAL 7 DAY);" +
            "SELECT  w.start ,w.finish, WEEKDAY(w.target_date) dayssa FROM aspnetusers u , work_period w WHERE u.Id=w.id_manager AND u.UserType=0 AND u.Id_num<>0 AND u.IsActive = TRUE AND target_date >= DATE_SUB('2018-04-21',INTERVAL 7 DAY);" +
            "SELECT DISTINCT u.ContactName ,w.description FROM aspnetusers u , work_period w WHERE u.Id=w.id_manager AND u.UserType=0 AND u.Id_num<>0 AND u.IsActive = TRUE AND w.target_date >= DATE_SUB('2018-04-21',INTERVAL 7 DAY);", conn);

        conn.Open();
        using (conn)
        {

            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.HasRows)
            //for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                var workperiod = new WorkPeriod1();
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    workperiod.Rtarget_date = reader.GetDateTime(0);              
                }

                reader.NextResult();
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    workperiod.RStart = Convert.ToDateTime(reader.GetString(0));
                    workperiod.RFinish = Convert.ToDateTime(reader.GetString(1));
                    workperiod.DWA = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetInt32(2));

                }
                reader.NextResult();
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    workperiod.RDescr = reader.GetString(1);
                    workperiod.RContactName = reader.GetString(0);        
                }
                reader.NextResult();
                model.Add(workperiod);
            }



            reader.Close();
```

Comment: Why not use `JOIN` and `LIMIT 5` statement to limit results to just 5 first entries in a single `SELECT` query? It is possible that only last part of query result obtained when `Read()` executed.

Comment: Added screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Use `while` instead of `if`:

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
   while (reader.Read())
   {
      .........
```

Comment: When i use while , model contain only last record.

Comment: Commonly used should be `if (reader.HasRows) {  while(reader.Read()) { ... } }`, since `HasRows` is `bool` property.